# Trying to connect Azure devops tp HP ALM 12.21 using Run from ALM Lab Managerment addon while executing pipeline getting error

Tags: azure-devops, hp-alm

Trying to connect Azure devops tp HP ALM 12.21  using Run from ALM Lab Managerment addon while executing pipeline getting error.

[image]

Comment: Can you also show the definitions? Don't know anything about ALM, but that error alone doesn't really tell much...

Comment: I have added definations

Comment: Ummm... No, you have not. Can you do it now?